# Doing a COW copy inside the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, memory, copy-on-write

So, I was wondering - how would I go about implementing **copying** memory pages (`struct page`) inside the kernel and utilizing the **copy-on-write** mechanism instead of transferring the data immediately.

Right now, I copy pages by converting userland addresses to pages, allocating the needed amount of pages using `allocate_pages` from the kernel, copying them using `copy_pages` and then finally mapping them into the desired region using `install_special_mapping`. This works but I feel like this could be optimized using the copy-on-write mechanism.

Comment: The question makes little sense, IMHO. If you always dirty the COW pages, there is no gain in using COW. If you seldomly dirty the new pages, there might be some gain. The gain is *not* in CPU time, but on (attached) memory usage. Also: COW causes a pagefault plus two context-switches per touched page, which is *very* expensive.

Comment: @wildplasser I haven't mentioned dirtying the pages anywhere.

Comment: But: what is in these pages, than? And: who puts it in there? And when?

Comment: @wildplasser The userland puts arbitrary data into those pages. For the purpose of this, we can assume that in 90% of the cases, the pages will not be modified so COW does actually have a purpose.